# Why might an executable be missing debug symbols when linked with gcc?

Tags: macos, debugging, gcc, gdb

Why is my executable missing its debug symbols?

I compile my source file to an object file:

```
g++ -g -O0 -c -std=c++11 -Wall -o build/foo.o src/foo.cpp
```

And then link:

```
g++ -g -L{/path1,/path2,...} -l{bar,baz,qux,...} -framework GLUT -framework OpenGL build/foo.o -o bin/foo
```

If I run `dwarfdump` on `build/foo.o`, I see a bunch of symbols. But `dwarfdump bin/foo` returns:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
 File: bin/foo (x86_64)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
.debug_info contents:
< EMPTY >
```

`gdb` also complains `No symbol table info available` when I run `info locals`.

What's going on? Why does the link step seem to destroy the debug symbol info?

I'm running gdb 7.7.1 and gcc 4.8.3 (both from MacPorts).

Comment: Do you get `dwarfdump` from your own gcc installation? The man page of the one installed with Xcode says that it's for 32-bit executables only.

Comment: @RetoKoradi: How do I tell for sure? If it's 32-bit only, how do I verify that the debug symbols are there? `file` doesn't say anything about whether the executable is stripped.

Comment: I always use the `nm` command to see symbols in object files. I wasn't familiar with `dwarfdump`, so I don't know what the difference is.

Comment: OK, I do see some info with `nm -a`, and I *think* it's debug info beyond just a normal symbol table. However the question remains why, if it's there, `gdb` won't make use of it.

Comment: Is it possible that you're using a mix of commands from different tool chains? For example, if you do `which g++` and `which gdb`, do they both come from the gcc/gdb you installed? I only use the standard development tools, so I can't really help with details. But it sounds like you use a mix of commands that don't all use/expect the same symbol table formats.